# Prove convergence for two metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let $(\mathbb{R},d_*)$ be a metric space, with:

$d_*(x,y)=|\frac{x}{1+|x|}-\frac{y}{1+|y|}|$

Now I have to show that this statement:

Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a convergent sequence of real numbers, then: 
$x_n\rightarrow x  \space  \text{in $(\mathbb{R},d_\mathbb{R})$} \iff x_n\rightarrow x  \space  \text{in $(\mathbb{R},d_*)$}$

Alright, (I think) we defined $d_{\mathbb{R}}(x,y)$ as being the standard Euclidean distance-function, so in this case: $d_{\mathbb{R}}(x,y)=|x-y|$

I suppose, the task is to show this:

$d_\mathbb{R}(x_n,x^*)<\epsilon \iff d_*(x_n,x^*)<\epsilon$

Which is the same as:

$|x_n-x^*|<\epsilon \iff |\frac{x_n}{1+|x_n|}-\frac{x^*}{1+|x^*|}|<\epsilon$

Am I right? But how can I do that? I really don't know how to get from the left side to the right side, does someone have a tip for me? Thanks in advance!

Also: does somebody know how $d_*$ actually looks like? Im quite curious.

Comment: It isn't precisely the same or rather the task you need to show isn't what you are thinking it to be. I think while proving you will also have to show that open balls by one metric can be expressed in terms of other.

Comment: I think you mean $d_{\mathbb{R}}$ as standard norm, is n't?

Comment: Sadly we don't know what a norm is yet, but I guess it is one.

Comment: Sorry standard Euclidean distance function

Comment: yes that is the task. You can multiply through by both denominators, do some cancellation inside $d_{*}$. Then you can say that $\frac{numerator}{(1+|x_n|)(1+|x|)} \leq \frac{|x_n-x|}{2} < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ as you want

Comment: Contrary to your post, it is $d_{\Bbb R}(x,y) = |x-y|$, not $d_*(x,y)$ which has the formula given at the start. However, you use it right in the rest of the post. $$|x_n-x^*|<\epsilon \iff |\frac{x_n}{1+|x_n|}-\frac{x^*}{1+|x^*|}|<\epsilon$$ **is false**, as can be most easily seen when $\epsilon = 2$, as the RH relation is always true, while the LH relation is false for most pairs. Fortunately, this is not needed to prove the required result $x_n\overset {d_{\Bbb R}}\to x \iff x_n\overset {d_*}\to x$. It is not required that they converge at the same speed.